# requestLegacyExternalStorage and foregroundServiceType are not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-12

First of all kindly excuse me if title seems like two issues are combined. But it's actually single issue belongs to `targetSdkVersion 31`.

As per android new app updates must target `Android 12` form **November 2022**. But when I try to build app targeting `Android 12` end up with following errors,

> AAPT: error: attribute android:foregroundServiceType not found.
>
> AAPT: error: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found.

This is how my `androidManifest.xml` file looks like,

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage ="true"
 >

 <service android:name=".service.TrackerService"
        android:process=":testTracker"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location" />
```

There is no error when I removed both from `androidManifest.xml`. I assume both `foregroundServiceType` and `requestLegacyExternalStorage` are not valid anymore in `Android 12`.

Is that safe to remove both `foregroundServiceType` and `requestLegacyExternalStorage` from `androidManifest.xml`?

**Note**: Though I am targeting `Android 12`, there are many users who are still using `Android 5`.

Comment: requestLegacyExternalStorage is still needed for your app to run on an Android 10 device. Well.. only of course if your app wants to read from or to write to external storage. You better show exactly how you declared them in manifest file.

Comment: I cannot test what i said as i do not program with react-native. But if you have an Android 10 device or emulator you could test if you could do without while reading or writing from external storage.

Comment: As @blackapps said, requestLegacyExternalStorage is needed to be able to access to files on android 10. Regarding foregroundServiceType, I'm not sure but I've read somewhere that services when marked as location get different behavior from the system so you'll probably need to find a workaround for that as well. Assuming what I remember is correct

Comment: @ThinkAndCode what is the compileSdkVersion you are using right now??

Comment: @Jeeva `minSdkVersion = 21`, `compileSdkVersion  = 31`, `targetSdkVersion = 31`,
 `buildToolsVersion = "31"`

Comment: @ThinkAndCode foregroundServiceType is needed check out this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types